# ViewPager не грузит картинки

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

может кто поймет в чем проблема: на первой item-е в recyclrview (лежащем во viewpagere-e) - погружаются картинки.
А на всех остальных - нет.

При том, если пролистать с Page1 до Page3, а затем вернуться на Pag1 - то и с первого item-а картинки пропадут

Репозиторий: https://github.com/covenant3717/FixViewPager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class FragmentDrinkItem(private val current: ItemHydro) : Fragment() {

//==============================================================================================

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_drink, container, false)

        initMain(view)

        return view
    }

    //==============================================================================================

    private fun initMain(root: View) {
        // title
        root.drink_item_tv.text = "${current.volume}мл"

        // image
        if (current.image.isNotEmpty()) {

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(current.image)
                    .into(root.drink_item_img)
        }


        isImageTouch(root)
    }

    private fun isImageTouch(root: View) {
        // меняю прозрачность картинки при клике

        root.drink_item_img.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->

            when (motionEvent.action) {
                ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    view.alpha = 0.7f
                }

                ACTION_UP, ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    view.alpha = 1.0f
                }
            }

            true
        }
    }

}


class SuperVpAdapter (fm: FragmentManager, private var list: List<String>) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    //==============================================================================================

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return SuperVpFragment()
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return list[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

}
```

Comment: приложите код который отвечает за показ картинок и перелистывание карточек

Comment: Отображение картинок:
https://github.com/covenant3717/FixViewPager/blob/32541fdedfa6e0c3cd5993d7f1dfb51bebcc6230/app/src/main/java/com/covenant/testvp2_in_vp2/vpinvp/FragmentDrinkItem.kt#L45-L44 

Адаптер перелистывающий карточки:
https://github.com/covenant3717/FixViewPager/blob/cda676bcf059ac426a3be16edec2ce82fecd7b03/app/src/main/java/com/covenant/testvp2_in_vp2/supervp/SuperVpAdapter.kt#L11-L10

Comment: Никто по вашим ссылкам бродить не будет, сюда код вставить можно

Comment: Не вопрос, рас вам здесь удобнее.

Comment: viewPager кэширует только смежные элементы, если перейти на 3 страницу, смежная с ней будет только 2. Т.е. информация на первой странице полностью пропадет - нужно либо рисовать заново, либо увеличить количество страниц для кэширования (осторожно может закончиться память).

Comment: Ваш совет подходит только к одному ViewPager, а у меня их там несколько в ресайклере. И все, кроме первого - не показывают свои данные

Comment: а у вас ни кода ни логов. читайте про работу viewpager - делайте тесты, изучайте когда какой метод срабатывает.

Comment: Где ваш метод `current.image` сделайте его массивом картинок и отображайте картинку по индексу, где в роли индекса будет выступать текущая страница `ViewPager`

Comment: Поясните, зачем? Какая рзница буду ли я ссылки грузить или картинки из проекта?

Comment: Попробовал. Это не решило мою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Я удивлен что у вас хотя бы на первой странице что-то подгружается. Вот почему:

В методе onCreateView вы создаете вьюшку, которую отдаете фрагменту. Вы сначала отдаете вьюшку, а потом отдаете ее фрагменту, и только после завершения метода onCreateView ваша вьюшка "прикрепится" к фрагменту, еще позже - к активити.

Внутри метода onCreateView вы вызываете initMain, где обращаетесь к вьюшкам через kotlin-ext механизмы. Но созданая для фрагмента вью еще не попала на активити или во фрагмент, и котлин(не уверен, но вроде так) не найдет ваши вьюшки.

Чтобы это работало надо вызов initMain вынести в функцию onViewCreated

Еще вы запускаете пикассо в `if (current.image.isNotEmpty())`. То есть если в imageView уже что-то есть, то загружаем картинку, а если там пусто, то ничего не делаем. Тут явно просится isEmpty